# How go display only values from query set? <QuerySet [<Matches: MUMBAI INDIANS (MI) VS CHENNAI SUPER KINGS (CSK),2020-09-19>]>

Tags: django, django-templates

I am learning Django and I am not able to display only values from this query set.
The template tags I am using is:

```
  {% for win in match_wins %}
      <td >{{ win.matchdetail.all }}</td>
  {% endfor %}
```

Views.py file

```
class MatchWinsView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'match_wins'
    model = models.Wins
    template_name = 'match_wins.html'
```

And my model looks like below:

```
class Wins(models.Model):
    matchdetail = models.ManyToManyField(Matches)
```

What should I fix to get only values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to also iterate over the `win.matchdetail.all` queryset.

```
{% for win in match_wins %}
    {% for matchdetail in win.matchdetail.all  %}
        {{ matchdetail }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```